# Unknown Column 'part.Name' in 'field list' in Select Statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to access the name of the partner (which is the Name column in table partner). However, it gives an error: Unknown column 'part.Name' in 'field list'.
My query goes as:

```
 Select productName,
       currentyear,
       currentmonth,
       FirstName,
       LastName,
       ReferrerId,
       (total_amount) AS total_amount,
       SUM(total_amount_usd) AS total_amount_usd,
       COUNT(productName) AS Purchases,
       UserName, 
       part.Name 
from ( 
        SELECT pro.Name AS productName,
               YEAR(CAST(c.CreatedOn AS date)) AS currentyear,
               MONTH(CAST(c.CreatedOn AS date)) AS currentmonth,
               c.Amount AS total_amount,
              (c.Amount * c.ExchangeRate) AS total_amount_usd,
               prof.FirstName UserName, 
               FirstName, 
               LastName, 
               ReferrerId, 
               part.Name
        FROM  PurchaseProduct p
        JOIN Purchase pur on p.PurchaseID = pur.Id
        JOIN Profile prof on prof.UserId = pur.UserId
        JOIN commerce c on p.PurchaseID = c.PurchaseID
        JOIN partner part on pur.PartnerId = part.Id
        JOIN Product pro on pro.Id = p.ProductId
        WHERE c.EventTypeId = 403
        AND part.TypeId = 6
       ) Result
WHERE  currentyear = 2022
GROUP BY currentyear, currentmonth, productName, UserName, part.Name
ORDER BY ProductName;
```

Even if I use partner.Name instead of part.Name (not mentioning alias at all), it starts giving Unknown column **partner.Name** in 'field list'. I double checked the spellings and cases but there's no issue in there.  
Can someone help me in figuring out why this error occurs?

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read, and to write.

Comment: There's no table `part` in the main query (where you used `part.Name`) but only in the inner query. Removing `part.` and using `name` only in the main query should fix the issue.

Comment: thanks so much The Impaler. 
I was wondering if you could help me in one small thing. When I use full name of table (i.e. partner) with Name column in the outer query, it still does not work. Only when I mention ONLY the column name in main query does it work fine. Can you kindly explain me why is that?